# how send notification to user when admin model save function in django admin site

Tags: django, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, django-admin

i am preparing an e commerce site where i want to send notification on orders like ( processing , dispatched, on the way etc. ) these items are filled by the admin in their site.

now my query is to send notification to the user when the admin fills the field and saves it.

```
class orders(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pid=models.ForeignKey(products,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount=models.FloatField()
    isaddfilled=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ispaymentdone=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    delivered=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    status=models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)
```

when the admin fills the status and saves it. the status should be sent as the
push notification to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Django allows you to assign signals to Model objects. These get executed when certain conditions happen on a model.

You can dive into the deep Django signal.

[signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/signals/)

using `pre_save` and `post_save` you will be able what you actually want.

Comment: i wanted to send push notification but i dont know any about it

Comment: your answer just confused me more because iam a beginer

Comment: Watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T6PyDm79PFo) carefully. I hope you will get the idea.